# The table column is always selected if the checkbox is clicked JQuery

Tags: jquery

How to solve the table column is always selected if the checkbox is clicked, this is my table code:

```
<table width="10%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>No.</th>
            <th>Nama</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="click">
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"></td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Adi</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and there is JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('tr#click td').click(function(e) {
        alert('Berhasil');
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $('#checkbox').click(function() {
        alert('Checkbox berhasil');
    });
});
```

Comment: stop the propagation on the click event for the checkbox.

Comment: @Taplar it's work, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Just add `stopPropagation()` to the checkbox click callback...

```
$('#checkbox').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('Checkbox berhasil');
});
```